# Require Permission On Sign In With GIS Client

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect, google-signin, google-api-js-client, google-identity

`gapi.oauth2` is being deprecated so I'm trying to set up Google Sign In using the new [GIS Client](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#library_quick_reference). However I'm having a serious issue when the user grants access to scopes. The checkbox for one of the scopes is unchecked by default. Users often forget to check this and then our app just won't work for them. With `gapi` I could handle this by [requesting additional permissions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) if they forgot to check the box. But the new GIS Client has no such functionality. Any ideas on how I might solve this problem? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in an OAuth flow, in such a case you would make a new authorization request with the complete list of scopes that you need. The authorization server should be able to tell that you are asking for more scopes than the user previously consented to and ask for a new consent. It seems that GIS Client is using a standard OAuth flow, so I would try to solve your problem this way.